# Having a really difficult time with Firebase and Android development

Tags: java, android, mobile

My group and I have a senior project, which involves an accelerometer and an Android mobile app. My groupmate was able to send accelerometer data into my database, however, I am not sure how to access it. In my database, it is being sent like this...

`petwatch-android-app-...`

`-> AcX: -11376`

`-> AcY: 9256`

`-> AcZ: 3240`

```
 - Users
     - User Unique ID
       -> Email
       -> Fullname
       -> Petname
       -> Petage
```

Is there anyway we would be able to send the accelerometer data to a specific person like with the unique user ID?

Comment: ya but first you need their unique id

Comment: @D_K if i were to have the unique id, what would be the code in order to send it directly to that specific user?

Comment: which database r u using ?? firestore ??

Comment: Firebase real-time database

Comment: refer this link you can learn much more things https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/